# VBA Close Word document after opening and not saving

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a piece of Macro script for opening a Word Document and export it to PDF. how can I add a piece which close the word document withouth saving??
Keep in mind the Word document must open as there are field in the document which needs to refresh

[image]

Any healp please
Thanks

Comment: Know that it would be better to paste the code. No one can copy/paste from the image to try what you have to help, and improve upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Now with correct code

```
Sub pdf()

Dim WordApp As Object
Dim WordDoc As Object
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With WordApp.Application
.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = .Documents.Open("C:\testdoc.docx")


WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    "C:\testdoc.docx.pdf", ExportFormat:= _
    17, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
    0, Range:=0, From:=1, to:=1, _
    Item:=0, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=0, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

'WordDoc.Application.Quit

Set WordDoc = Nothing
End With
Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Just for your information, you can edit your original question by clicking the little 'edit' button below it. You are not supposed to add 'answers' as part of your question.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm pretty new to the forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `WordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges` before the `Set WordDoc = Nothing`

Also, if you want to quit the program entirely you should indeed send the command to quit it before setting the variable to `Nothing`:

```
WordApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
```

Other options for the `Quit` and `Close` methods can be found in the documentation: [Application.Quit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.quit(method)); [Document.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.close(method)).

Your final code might look like this:

```
Sub pdf()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    WordApp.Visible = True

    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\testdoc.docx")

    WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        "C:\testdoc.docx.pdf", ExportFormat:= _
        17, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        0, Range:=0, From:=1, to:=1, _
        Item:=0, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=0, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

    'If you want to quit the entire Application:
    WordApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

    'If you want to quit only the Document:
    'WordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```